# Capturing browser JS console output for automated tests

Tags: javascript, browser, console

We are running JS functional / integration tests (in a browser) via CI.  They include synchronous and asynchronous tests using the YUI Test framework.  Tests run, results are collected and posted to a custom result file writer.

One problem that we have been facing is that tests are timing out from time to time presumably because of a JS exception.

I'm curious if there is a way to listen in some way to anything that goes to the browser's console whether console.debug() or exception info.  Our target browsers for this project are Chrome and Safari.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For chrome you can use the tool name sawbuck this is tool is similar to dbgview it lets you see all the console logs.

see https://code.google.com/p/sawbuck/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think there is a way. WebKit's Console object has become almost FireBug's identical, prototype-wise, so you can have a look at FireBug's [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API). Of course, you can always mock-up the developer's tool and look at the Console's prototype (simply type console and look at its `__proto__` method.

If you just want to catch errors sent to the console, why not use a `try...catch` statement?

Comment: Unfortunately I have found no place to put a try/catch that will cover us particularly for anything asynchronous.  I'm heading down the Console API route now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tom - Why don't you just add everything in a try catch? If you get specific types of errors for asynchronous calls, you can use the instanceof operator to filter out errors, and then use error.message to get the actual message. That way you can add error handling that'll make your script run even if there were errors.